# Why does Andengine show errors after restarting Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

First off I'm running Eclipse Juno with ADT v20.0.3.I'm following [this tutorial](https://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/setting-up-andengine-gles2-0/) and did the software update.

After importing Andengine as a GIT using the URL there were literally thousands of errors. I fixed it changing the compliance settings to 1.6. All errors were removed. I imported Andengine Examples and it showed thousands of errors which are almost identical. So i changed the compliance to 1.6 did a clean and still the same errors. I restarted Eclipse and now Andengine library is showing a small red x but doesn't tell me why and nothing ever changed.

Didn't find anything helpful on google or on here. I wondered if this is just my computer doing this or is there really something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I did a cleanup now Andengine isn't showing errors but Andengine Examples still has thousands of errors.

Comment: Ok I guess my problem is I haven't downloaded the extensions needed for the examples. They're all on code.google.com

Comment: Now I can't figure out what Andengine_src, Andengine1_src is downloaded from.

Answer (score 2):

[AndEngine](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine) as well as all [extensions](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine#extensions) are hosted on [github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine).

FYI: Not saying what compile errors you have makes it hard to help.

There is nothing such as **Andengine_src**, or **Andengine1_src**. Simply add AndEngine as an Android Library Project to your project and that's it.